# How can I change the browser title?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, openerp-7

By default the browser title says either

```
OpenERP
```

or, once in the system, something like

```
Partners - OpenERP
```

How can I change that to include my company's branding?

```
Partners - My Cool Company
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a master module for your installation -- `my_cool_company`, for example:

`__init__.py`

```
from openerp.addons.web.controllers import main

main.html_template = main.html_template.replace(
    '<title>OpenERP</title>',
    '<title>My Cool Company</title>'
    )
```

---

`__openerp__.py`

```
.
.
.
'depends': [
    'web',
    ],
'js': [
    'static/src/js/branding.js',
    ],
.
.
.
```

---

`static/src/js/branding.js`

```
openerp.my_cool_company = function(instance) {
    instance.web.WebClient.include({
        set_title: function(title) {
            title = _.str.clean(title);
            var sep = _.isEmpty(title) ? '' : ' - ';
            document.title = title + sep + 'My Cool Company';
        },
    });
};
```